# Error while trying to ssh into Linux VM on GCP

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I'd like to know if you've come across this error and possible solution.
I've gone through alot to fix this, but doesn't seem to work.

Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Comment: You can find detailed answer on [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/890374/unable-to-ssh-onto-gce-vm-after-reboot)

Comment: You can find the detailed answer on [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/890374/unable-to-ssh-onto-gce-vm-after-reboot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the guide on [Connecting to Linux Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance). The different options are(see link for details):

- Connecting using Compute Engine tools
- Connecting using third-party tools
- Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses

A very important issue with this last one, and the possible cause of your error is to set up the firewall rule, add a tag to it and then add this tag to your instance:

> ...
>
> **Note:** Your Google Cloud Platform VPC network must have one or more firewall rules that allow SSH connections on port 22. The firewall
>   rules must allow SSH connections for the IP ranges or specific IP
>   addresses from which you want to connect.
>
> ...

See [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) about firewall rules and in step 8 of this codelab, you learn how to enable a rule. In you case your **Destination protocol and port** will be `tcp:22` and not `tcp:80`.

Before setting the rule, if I try to connect using this command:

**perezprado@trainingperezprado:~$** `gcloud compute ssh perezdesktop`

I receive the same error message:

```
ssh: connect to host 00.111.222.333 port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

On the other hand, this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27158218/9015852). Apparently:

> .....someone else in your project set the per-instance metadata for
>   sshKeys (which overrides the project-wide metadata)....

See the link for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using SSH command or some third party tool to get in into your `Google compute` instance. It accepts only SSH-key based logins. You will have to add those keys manually through a `SSH console` opened from `Google Compute` console website.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I added ssh-keys at the project level (Console: Compute Engine -> Metadata -> SSH Keys).  The problem was resolved after I added ssh-keys at the os-login level:

```
gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add \
    --key-file [KEY_FILE_PATH] \
    --ttl [EXPIRE_TIME]
```

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin